# Interact with a marker with user location

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

I have implemented `react-native-maps` with Expo, and I want to create a little game. I have the user location and I want to create an event for example; if I'm from 5 meters of a marker, I want to to do something.

I don't know if it's possible, I think there is something to do with the lat and long of the user with the the lat and long of the marker... There is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import { MapView,Location,Permissions } from 'expo';

export default class Game extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Map',
};

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        locationResult:{ latitude: 0, longitude: 0},
        errorMessage: null,
        hasLocationPermissions: false,
        region: null,
        location:null
    }
}

  _OnDragEnd = result =>{
    this.setState({locationResult: result.coordinate})
    console.log(this.state.locationResult)
    console.log(result.coordinate)
    if (result.coordinate == this.state.locationResult){
      console.log('ok')
    }else{
      console.log('pas ok')
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  _handleMapRegionChange = region => {
    console.log(region);
    this.setState({ region });
  };

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ hasLocationPermissions: true });
    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    this.setState({
      region: { 
        latitude: location.coords.latitude, 
        longitude: location.coords.longitude, 
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922 / 10, 
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421 / 10 },
      locationResult:{
        latitude: location.coords.latitude,
        longitude: location.coords.longitude},
      location
    });
  };

  _reachSpawn = async () => {

  }

  mapStyle = require('./mapStyle.json');

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>  
        <Text style={{height:40,backgroundColor: '#6AC4ED'}}>Score: </Text>
        <MapView
          showsUserLocation
          followsUserLocation
          style={{flex:1}}
          region={this.state.region}
          zoomEnabled={false}
          pitchEnabled={false}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          customMapStyle={this.mapStyle}
          provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          showsCompass={true}
        >
        {/* <MapView.Marker
          //image = '../../../assets/DarkSamus.png'
          coordinate={this.state.locationResult}
            title="My Marker"
            description="Some description"
            draggable
            onDragEnd={e => this._OnDragEnd(e.nativeEvent)}
            image={require('../../../assets/soldier-6.png')}
        /> */}
      {
        SPAWNS.map((m, i) =>
          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={m.latLong}
            title={m.title}
            description={m.description}
            key={`marker-${i}`}
            pinColor= '#20794C'
            image={require('../../../assets/zombie-4.png')}
          />
        )
      }
        </MapView>
      </View>
      );
  }
}

const SPAWNS = [
  {
    key: 'Zombie',
    title: 'Zombie Level 1',
    description: 'Kill him to get 1 point',
    latLong: {
      latitude: 48.78356518226211,
      longitude: 2.3951343385137105,
    },
  },
  {
    key: 'Zombie',
    title: 'Zombie Level 1',
    description: 'Kill him to get 1 point',
    latLong: {
      latitude: 48.869702,
      longitude: 2.335888,
    },
  },
  {
    key: 'Zombie',
    title: 'Zombie Level 1',
    description: 'Kill him to get 1 point',
    latLong: {
      latitude: 48.77993070617117,
      longitude: 2.3956984115292626,
    },
  },
  {
    key: 'Zombie',
    title: 'Zombie Level 1',
    description: 'Kill him to get 1 point',
    latLong: {
      latitude: 48.780455052145385,
      longitude: 2.4131448702847615,
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: Have you tried using the 'onUserLocationChange' event and then calculating the distance between your markers and the user location (the event gives you the user coordinates)? You can cycle through your markers and check the distance from each of them. Once you have this distance you can trigger your function/event if it's below the threshold

Comment: @Jono I have to put a function in onUserLocationChange, but how to get here the currentLocation coordinates, and do the calculation ?

Comment: The function that you put into onUserLocationChange will return the user's current location. Check in the docs here - https://github.com/expo/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md
In the function that you declare pass the value through 
userChange = location => {...}

Comment: @Jono how works latitude and longitude calculation ? to see if I'm close from a marker ??

Comment: You can use a package like this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib
Or you can implement a function like this:

var getDistance = function(p1, p2) {
  var R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
  var dLat = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
  var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) *
    Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c;
  return d; // returns the distance in meter
};